# How to uppload a large file using Lambda, when presigned URL's are not an option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to develop a public API for our application. It's running in AWS Lambda and uses S3 as storage. Now the problem is, that this public API should be able to handle file upploads. Files can be bigger then 6mb, so out of Lambda limits.

Using presigned URL's with direct file uppload to S3 is a good option for our internal use, but in case of public API, it may be confusing for the consumers.

It's not so clear for services, that will use the API, why should they do a call to receive presigned url, uppload the file to this url and do one more confirmation request to our API.

I'd like to make it as clear as possible for the consumers, but have no idea how to handle it.

The only one thing I could invent is creating a proxy EC2 instance. The API url will lead to this instance and it will handle the request:

1. If it's a simple request to store json data, it will directly call
   the endpoint in our application to store it in DB
2. If it's a file
   uppload request, it will uppload the file to S3 and then call an
   application endpoint, so application can handle the file uppload
   request and return a response

But that's very tricky way, so I'm thinking  on some simpler options

Comment: API Gateway has a 10MB payload limit, so sending uploads to an EC2 instance isn't going to help much. The fact is API Gateway just doesn't handle large file uploads at all. S3 presigned URLs are the recommended work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Api Gateway to S3 integration is one way how to do it:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/

This is the part of the document which mentions the integration.

> Now, Select Integration Request and select AWS Service under the
> Integration type category. For AWS Region, choose us-west-2. For AWS
> Service, choose Simple Storage Service (S3).

Comment: API Gateway still has a 10MB payload size limit. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html That's not much better than the 6MB Lambda payload limit.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can use Lambda with up to 10GB of Ephemeral Storage now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-ephemeral-storage

EDIT: I see the payload limit is not the problem here, thanks [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b).

Two potential options:

**Option 1**

The S3 Presigned URL option is not bad if you are interacting with your own web/mobile applications. You put the Lambda behind your standard user authentication/authorization and then return a payload like:

```
{
  "upload_url": "<presigned url>"
}
```

Then the client can simply pass the file to the upload url you specify in the response.

**Option 2**

If you are building a Public Programmatic API, one in which you don't want to leak S3 details, then I would recommend implementing multi-part file upload. You can do this with API Gateway and AWS Lambda, ensuring that each upload is within the limits of each of those services. In this approach, you will need to design and implement API that feels natural to the client. The AWS S3 CLI does multi-part upload under the covers.

Comment: That's the local storage limit, not the payload limit. The question is related to the payload limit.